# How to trigger custom order status woocommerce email only for specific conditions

Tags: woocommerce

Hi there I have added a custom order status called "payment instructions" and I have also added a custom email template for this status.
Now I want that this email template should be only be triggered when two conditions are true.
Cond-1: If the order status is "on-hold".
Cond-2: If the payment method chosen by the customer is " Credit Card".
I have added the following code in my functions.php but it doesn't seem to work.

```
// Trigger "Payment Instructions" notification for Credit card orders
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_payment-instructions', 'email_payment_instructions_notification_for_credit_card', 2, 20 );
function email_payment_instructions_notification_for_credit_card( $order_id, $order ) {
    if( $order->get_payment_method_title() == 'CREDIT CARD (15% ADDITIONAL FEE)' && $order->get_status == 'on-hold' )
        WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_order_status_email_payment_instructions']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

How can I make it work? or Should I use any other code for this?